# IBM zCX - how to autostart the docker application when zCX instance boots up

Tags: docker, containers, websphere, mainframe

I have a docker application. It is running fine on IBM zCX docker environment. Every time the LPAR is IPLed and zCX reboots, I will have to start my docker container manually. I checked the getting started guide for IBM zCX. It does not talk about how to start the docker application when zCX boots up every-time.

On Linux, I used either init.d or systemd service to auto-start my docker containers.

What is the recommended way to autostart the docker container when zCX server comes up?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify --restart option in the docker run command.

Every time, the Docker engine will be starting (so at zCX boot time), it will automatically restart the container.

Comment: I think, you are referring to - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

```
docker run -d --restart unless-stopped redis
```

Comment: Yes. Or "docker run -d --restart always redis" for uncontional restart.when Docker daemon restarts.